# Wordpress srcset in the_content

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is not applying srcset to images added in the editor and displayed through the_content(). Is there a way to fix this? I have been searching for an answer but no joy!

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, The images were added by my client through importing hence they are missing srcset. I should have tried adding an actual image before spending ages searching for an answer. Cest la vie!